# My.Settings.mytext has a value but i cannot find where it is set?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

onload i do a msgbox (my.settings.mytext)

it returns a value, but i cannot find where in the project i have set this value!! it was definitely set by me, but i cannot find it anywhere. please help

it is attached to textbox1.text, but that has no value either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see [`My.Settings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/saa62613(VS.80).aspx):

> The My.Settings object provides access
>   to the application's settings and
>   allows you to dynamically store and
>   retrieve property settings and other
>   information for your application. For
>   more information, see Managing
>   Application Settings.

and also [How to: Add or Remove Application Settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/25zf0ze8(VS.80).aspx):

> Application settings allow you to
>   store and retrieve property settings
>   and other information for your
>   application dynamically. There are two
>   types of application settings, based
>   on scope: user-scoped and
>   application-scoped settings.
>
> At design time, you can add
>   application settings either using the
>   Settings pane of the Project Designer,
>   or ***using the Properties window for a
>   form or control, which allows you to
>   bind a setting directly to a property.***

This last line that I have emphasized is most likely where you want to look.

Comment: andrew, thank you very much for your help, but this doesnt answer my question. my problem is finding where i have set its value

Comment: I believe I did answer the question - those settings are managed via the settings pane of the project's properties dialog.  Please click through the second link I posted for a step-by-step tutorial on that process.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could goto the Edit menu and do a Quick Find on the Settings name, if it finds it you'll probably find out where you've set the value.

Also, have you checked the Program.vb file? I always forget about that file.

Hope this has helped.